# FASM pass by reference/pointer

Tags: assembly, fasm

I'm trying to write an assembly function that allocates memory and stores the address in a given pointer. However, I cannot figure out how to store the address in the parameter passed to the function.

I have the following:

```
struc SSLSocket sock, ssl, ctx, address, port, connected, type
{
   .sock dd sock
   .ssl dd ssl
   .ctx dd ctx
   .address dd address
   .port dw port
   .connected db connected
   .type dd type
}

SockArray dd 0  //will allocate 5 of the above struct on the heap and store it in this pointer.

section '.code' code readable executable
main:
   push ebp
   mov ebp,esp


   ;push 5
   ;call [malloc]
   ;add esp, 0x04
   ;mov [SockArray], eax

   push SockArray   ;pointer that will hold allocated memory
   push 23         ;size of struct
   call ReAllocate_Memory
   add esp, 0x08

   push [SockArray] //print address of allocated memory.
   push PrintPtr
   call [printf]
   add esp, 0x08


   mov esp, ebp
   pop ebx

   call [getchar]

   mov eax, 0x00
ret

ReAllocate_Memory:
   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp

   mov eax, [ebp + 0x0C]      ;Pointer that will hold address of allocation
   mov edx, [ebp + 0x08]      ;Size to allocate in bytes

   push eax
   call [free]                ;Free any allocated memory
   add esp, 0x04

   push edx
   call [malloc]              ;Allocate n-size bytes
   add esp, 0x04

   ;mov address into parameter pointer ([ebp + 0x0C]).

   mov esp, ebp
   pop ebp
ret
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store the new pointer in `ReAllocate_Memory` since you don't have the address of it within that routine.

Either

- modify that routine to take a pointer to the variable (get and pass the address with `lea eax, SockArray; push eax` or similar) and then load the parameter and store to it with e.g. `mov edx, [ebp + 0x10]` then `mov [edx], eax`.

or else, and this is way easier:

- don't attempt to store the new pointer in `ReAllocate_Memory`. Since it is returned in `eax` you can simply store it in the calling scope, same as you do after the `malloc` call.

Aside: loading `edx` with a value and then calling a function (`free`) is dangerous: sub-routines are not required to preserve the value of `edx`. Better not to load that until after `free` returns, even if it happens to currently work.

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand all of that since I'm fairly new to asm still. I did: http://pastebin.com/fYUXBkeW and it seems to work. I had to save `edx` and other registers because it'd crash otherwise. You were correct about that. I understood a bit of what you were saying but not all. Specifically the `easier way`. I accept this answer because I understand most of it and the saving register parts saved me :D

Comment: Let me see if I can explain it better: In `ReAllocate_Memory` you call `malloc` for the new buffer. The result from `malloc` is returned in `eax`. If you just leave it there and return to the caller without doing anything, the value will still be there in the calling scope when `ReAllocate_Memory` returns, and you can store it same as you do (albeit commented out) with the original `malloc` call further up.

Comment: OHHH I see! I did not think about that. I had my mind stuck on getting it to work with parameters to think about the return value. Ahaha. That was a much better explanation. Thank you! :D